# problems in checking the form input values before submitting using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my code is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // this is a button to add the form to the DOM tree.
    $("#submitPara").click(function() {
        $("body").append('<form id = "dimensionAndObjects" action = "#"></form>');
        some code to add some input fields, omitted...
        $('#dimensionAndObjects').append('<p><input id = "submitDO" type = "submit" value = "submit"></input></p>');
        return true;
    });

    $('#dimensionAndObjects').submit(function() {
        alert("haahhhahhaha");
        return false;
    });

});
```

it seems that the submit function doesn't work because the alert info doesn't appear.
if i put the submit function inside the click function, it doesn't work either.
what's wrong? I am a totally freshman to jQuery, thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4):

since the form is created dynamically you need to use event delegation

```
$(document).on('submit', '#dimensionAndObjects', function() {
        alert("haahhhahhaha");
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: +1 for seeing the need to attach to document, with the way the code is structured.

Comment: if we passed a handler to the submit function instead of performing the submit it would attach the handler to the submit event. Thats why the submit didn't happen right?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dimensionAndObjects').live('click',function(e) {
e.preventdefault();
        alert("haahhhahhaha");
        return false;// for not submit the form
return true ;// for submit the form
    });
```